# Combine two queries in one request

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to execute multiple queries on elasticsearch server with one request. Specifically I have the following query (is on elastcisearch-php-client)

```
$params = [
                    "index" => "bookydate",
                    "type" => "vendor_service",
                    "body" => [
                        "query" => [
                            "bool" => [
                                "must" => [
                                    "term" => [
                                        "sys_service_id" => $request->input("sys_service_id")
                                    ]
                                ],
                                "should" => [ 
                                    "geo_shape" => [
                                        "served_location" => [
                                            "shape" => [
                                                "type" => "point",
                                                "coordinates" => [
                                                    "{$request->input('loc_lon')}",
                                                    "{$request->input('loc_lat')}"]
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
```

What I want to do is the fetch also all the documents that have the `"hole_country"` field to `true`.

What I have tried already is to make another request to Elasticsearch server and with `array_merge` combine the two results, but did not work because of PHP restrictions on arrays with multiple same keys.

**UPDATE**

Elastcisearch supports a feature called `Multisearch` that is exactly what im looking for. The problem is that php-client does not support multisearch so I have to use Guzzle in order to send the requests.

Guzzle docs does not have a full info about how to construct a correct request body. Any info is welcome

Already i have the following body but elastcisearch is returing bad request error

```
    $body = [
        ["index"=>"bookydate"],
        ["query"=>["bool"=> ["must"=>[["term"=>["sys_service_id"=>"1"]],["geo_shape"=>["served_location"=>["shape"=>["type"=>"circle","coordinates"=>[25,3],"radius"=>"90km"]]]]]]]],
        ["index"=>"bookydate"],
        ["query"=>["bool"=>["must"=>["term"=>["hole_country"=>true]]]]]
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the multisearch API of Elasticsearch. This is more or less appending all your queries as JSON format in a single POST request. I hope the PHP client supports this, otherwise you might have to manually do the POST request.

[Multi-search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)

Comment: multisearch if fine for me and fits my needs. Indeed php-client does not support msearch so I used guzzle in order to send request. But I have to address some issues about how to send the correct body. Please see my update

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not documented the [Multi Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) is supported by the elasticsearch php client.

Instead of `search` call `msearch`, and group your queries like this:

`$params = [
    'body' => [
      ["index" => "bookydate", "type" => "vendor_service"],
      ["query" => [
        "bool" => [
            "must" => [
                "term" => [
                    "sys_service_id" => $request - > input("sys_service_id")
                ]
            ],
            "should" => [
                "geo_shape" => [
                    "served_location" => [
                        "shape" => [
                            "type" => "point",
                            "coordinates" => [
                                "{$request->input('loc_lon')}",
                                "{$request->input('loc_lat')}"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]]
];`

So using your updated syntax is correct. You must just call [msearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/418f3fbdba8792a354547853aac7a315d2b3575e/src/Elasticsearch/Client.php#L630).